# Где связывается главный класс GWT-приложения и html-страница запуска?

Tags: java, gwt

Я где-то в IDEA разорвал связь html-страницы c главным запускающим классом, теперь выводится только HTML страничка без контролов и прочей логики.

Подскажите куда смотреть плз?

**Main.gwt.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 2.0//EN"
        "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/releases/2.0/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
<module>

    <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>

    <entry-point class='ru.javastudy.gwtPersistence.client.Main'/>

    <!-- Inherit the UiBinder module.                               -->
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.uibinder.UiBinder"/>

    <!-- Specify the paths for translatable code -->

    <source path='client' />
    <source path='shared' />

    <!-- Specify the app servlets.                   -->
    <servlet path='/MainRpcService' class='ru.javastudy.gwtPersistence.server.MainRpcServiceImpl'/>

</module>
```

**Main.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Main Application</title>

    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Main.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="ru.javastudy.gwtPersistence.Main.nocache.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
...
</body>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>ru.javastudy</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwtPersistence</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <properties>
        <gwtVersion>2.6.0</gwtVersion>
        <hibernate-version>5.1.0.Final</hibernate-version>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- ensure all GWT deps use the same version (unless overridden) -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
                <artifactId>gwt</artifactId>
                <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt</artifactId>
            <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
            <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-codeserver</artifactId>
            <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-dev</artifactId>
            <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- javax -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- PostgreSQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.4-1205-jdbc42</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-search-infinispan</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>

        <outputDirectory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>ru.javastudy.gwtPersistence.client.Main</mainClass>
                            <packageName>ru.javastudy.gwtPersistence.client</packageName>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <includeScope>compile</includeScope>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webXml>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <port>8080</port>
                    <hostedWebapp>war</hostedWebapp>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

    </build>

</project>
```

Хочу сказать, что у меня разрывается связь html-страницы c gwt-приложением, сразу же после того, как я переношу Main.html и Main.css из папки public модуля в папку webapp. Если этого не сделать, то после компоновки war-ника, томкат не может найти Main.html

Да собственно и хотелось бы знать, что нужно сделать, чтобы после переноса Main.html и Main.css в блок webapp связь не рвалась?

Answer (score 2):

Приветствую.

Наконец то нашел решение своего вопроса.
Как оказалось, не смотря на всю структурную схожесть с тем что должно быть, мое gwt-приложение было изначально то ли с ошибкой, то ли неверно сконфигурировано.

Буквально "на коленках" создал пустой Maven-проект, добавил поддержку GWT с параллельным созданием простейшего приложения, чтобы правильно выстроилась структура (`client`, `server`, `public`, `shared`).

Теперь, html-страница и соседствующий css-файл преспокойно переносятся в `src\main\webapp`.

Нормально компилируется как GWT так и TomCat приложение. Что это было? Я не знаю. В качестве предположения допускаю, что где-то неправильно прописался конфиг в дебрях IntellijIDEA.

Но факт остается фактом: два рядом лежащие приложения как две капли воды похожие друг на друга, идентичные в структурном плане - но одно запускается, второе нет. War-ник получился со всеми необходимыми библиотеками на 30MB.

Answer (score 0):

В файле `имя_модуля.gwt.xml` есть строка

```
<entry-point class='полный.путь.к.классу'/>
```

Также в твоей html'ке должно быть вытягивание сгенерированного скрипта примерно так

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"
            src="полное_имя_модуля/имя_точки_входа.nocache.js"></script>
```

Comment: Вроде бы всё верно указал. И всё равно, сразу HTML-страница, даже сообщение о компиляции модуля не видно в серой рамочке ((

Comment: @vard32 приложи содержимое этих файлов и файла pom.xml